# LLDB po command encoding format of "\332"

Tags: objective-c, lldb

So I got a NSData from backend server, my backend engineer folk says there is a simple decoding logic and I have to get the second byte.

So I have turned this NSdata into bytes array via

`const unsigned char *usageBuf = (unsigned char *)[keyData bytes];`

When I print it on LLDB, it outputs like:

> (lldb) po usageBuf
>   "\x16\332d\336C\xa2Jc\x88./Q\374\326[\x01\x01\xa8\314\x96\x8d\320.c\x8bѐ\r\xb7'\317\366\342\206>\x1fE\322e\x91\311\354\302"

however when I try to print usageBuf[1], it's like:

```
(lldb) po usageBuf[0]
'\x16'

(lldb) po usageBuf[1]
'\xda'

(lldb) po/x usageBuf[1]
0xda

(lldb) po usageBuf[2]
'd'
```

I am confused how '\332' turned into '\xda'? I searched the UTF8 table, but it just says `UTF-8 0x5C 0x33 0x33 0x32`, so I must be missing some puzzles, please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of numerical base:

hex `DA` == dec `218` == oct `332`

Comment: so how do I know it's oct? UTF8 is oct based?

Comment: I am asking this because the first byte is \x16, and second is \332, then the third byte is 'd', so '\x16' and 'd' seems hex, but \332 is oct, shouldn't they be consistent base/format? e.g. when I print usageBuf, it gives '\x16\xdad'

Comment: Check the code for LLDB.  It's choosing the output format.

Comment: Octal is just a numeric representation.  UTF8 is byte-based, and how you print each byte in a debugger's output is irrelevant.

Comment: so you are saying, the behavior of LLDB is how it is implemented? I just can't see a clear idea how it prints

Comment: Of course the implementation of LLDB defines its behavior.  It's not sentient, you know.